# Inserting back from select another values

Tags: mysql

i have one table

```
|| *content_id* || *content_value* || *content_const* || *language_language_id* ||
|| 1 || title_1 || heading_1 || 1 ||
|| 2 || title_2 || heading_2 || 1 ||
|| 23 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 1 ||
|| 24 || subtitle_2 || sub_2 || 1 ||
|| 50 || title_1 || heading_1 || 2 ||
|| 51 || title_2 || heading_2 || 2 ||
|| 48 || title_2 || heading_2 || 3 ||
|| 53 || title_1 || heading_1 || 3 ||
```

i need inserting back to the table the values with language_id what actually exist in the table (in that case with id 2 and 3) what what i added with whatever language id . what is the proper way do this?

i need the results:

```
|| *content_id* || *content_value* || *content_const* || *language_language_id* ||
|| 1 || title_1 || heading_1 || 1 ||
|| 2 || title_2 || heading_2 || 1 ||
|| 23 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 1 ||
|| 24 || subtitle_2 || sub_2 || 3 ||
|| 48 || title_2 || heading_2 || 3 ||
|| 50 || title_1 || heading_1 || 2 ||
|| 51 || title_2 || heading_2 || 2 ||
|| 53 || title_1 || heading_1 || 3 ||
|| 62 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 1 ||
|| 63 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 2 ||
|| 64 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 2 ||
|| 65 || subtitle_1 || sub_1 || 3 ||
```

i have one query what give me the good result without language id. `SELECT * FROM .content GROUP BY .content.content_const HAVING COUNT(.content.content_const) = 1` but i need it inserting back with other language id... :(
thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just process results you've got from your first query and create a INSERT query which will insert data you want back to the table.

[more info about INSERT query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

This is pretty basic stuff, you should try taking a sql tutorial somewhere on the web, it should help you understand basic about sql queries.